# Attempt to present <JSSAlertView.JSSAlertView...which is already presenting

Tags: ios, mobile, uiviewcontroller, swift3, cocoapods

I'm working on simple countdown timer(Swift). When the time reaches "0", I want to show the alertView. For that I'm using JSSAlertView pod.

Everything works well, but with that alertView I'm also getting this: **Warning: Attempt to present   on  which is already presenting**

How can I fix it?

I don't use the Storyboard or Xib file. Everything was written programmatically.
I v'e tried different solutions found using Google - nothing worked for me.

P.S.
I've attached my code below. I have two ViewControllers:

First viewController has start button:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

func startButtonCLicked(_ button: UIButton) {
        let controller = SecondViewController()
        present(controller, animated: true)
  }
}
```

Second viewController has timer function and alertView:

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

 func updateTimer() {
        if seconds > 0 {
            print(seconds)
            seconds -= 1

            timerLabel.text = String(Timer.timeFormatted(seconds))

        } else {
            let alertview = JSSAlertView().show(self,
                                                title: "Hey",
                                                text: "Hey",
                                                buttonText: "Hey",
                                                color: UIColorFromHex(appColor.hexMainOrangeColor, alpha: 1))

            alertview.setTextTheme(.light)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        if timer.isValid == false {
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(SecondViewController.updateTimer) , userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }
      } 
    }
```

Cheers!

Comment: don't know with JSAlertview but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36450931/countdown-in-uialertcontroller might help

Comment: Thank you Mike Alter, but it's a little bit different...My friend just helped me to solve that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

I was getting that error because as soon as "seconds == 0" I started constantly called alertView:

```
func updateTimer() {
        if seconds > 0 {
            print(seconds)
            seconds -= 1
            timerLabel.text = String(Timer.timeFormatted(seconds))
        } else {
            let alertview = JSSAlertView().show(self,
                                                title: "Hey",
                                                text: "Hey",
                                                buttonText: "Hey",
                                                color: UIColorFromHex(appColor.hexMainOrangeColor, alpha: 1))
            alertview.setTextTheme(.light)
        }
    }
```

to fix it, I created global Bool - secondsLeft and assigned it to false. I put this Bool inside my code like this:

```
func updateTimer() {
        if seconds > 0 {
            print(seconds)
            seconds -= 1

            timerLabel.text = String(Timer.timeFormatted(seconds))

        } else if seconds == 0 && !secondsLeft {

            secondsLeft = true
            let alertview = JSSAlertView().show(self,
                                                title: "Hey",
                                                text: "Hey",
                                                buttonText: "Hey",
                                                color: UIColorFromHex(appColor.hexMainOrangeColor, alpha: 1))

            alertview.setTextTheme(.light)
            alertView.addAction(
            self.dismiss(self, animated: true, completion: nil))
        }
    }
```

Now before to call alertView I'm checking if seconds == 0 and secondsLeft == false. If yes, alertView shows up, secondsLeft becomes - true, and I'm not calling alertView anymore. 
Inside viewDidAppear I assign secondsLeft to false again.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        secondsLeft = false

        if timer.isValid == false {
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(SecondViewController.updateTimer) , userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }
      } 
    }
```

So, it works...but now I'm getting another `Warning: Attempt to present <JSSAlertView.JSSAlertView: 0x7feb1c830a00> on <MyApp.TimerViewController: 0x7feb1be05650> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`

Any ideas?